# Java Changing Characters into 2D Graphics

Tags: java, graphics2d

I open a text file which contains a maze, that consists of # and spaces.   Where a hash tag represents a "wall" and the spaces are the area that you can move through.

Currently I have opened the file and stored everything in a 2d array so that the console prints out in the exact format as the text file.

My next stage that I am trying to accomplish is, if the char is a hash tag, fill the rectangle with a dark grey, if its a space fill it with white. At the moment for some reason the maze is showing up but appearing really small.

I don't know if I took the right approach but I am trying to modify the method I have rather than creating another method.

Essentially I want to fill up that whole 600x400 with my maze rather than it being so small. I thought setting the size of the rectangle would achieve this.

What I am trying is:

```
public static void mazeFrame() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Maze");
    f.setSize(400, 600);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.add(new Exercise4());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

```
// ...

    int i = 0; //y axis

    if (c == '#') {
        cells[i][j] = true;
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawRect(j,i, 50,50);
    } else {
        cells[i][j] = false;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(j,i, 50,50);

    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

But my output is

[image]

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest not to do the painting at the same time as reading from the file. Read the maze from the file *once*. Use `paintComponent` to draw the maze from its *representation in memory*. Remember there are many repaint events, whenever you move other windows over your window, resize, etc.

Comment: @RealSkeptic that was my initial idea however i wasn't sure on how to grab the cell i,j values etc from the method to a "paintComponent" method.

Comment: You're supposed to have the maze in a *field* in the class, not in a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not scaling your maze.

```
 g.drawRect(j,i, 50,50);
```

The values for `j` and `i` both start at 0 and are incremented by one.
As a consequence, your 50x50 blocks overlap.

If you'd add a scale factor, your maze would be bigger:

```
 g.drawRect(xScale * j, yScale * i, 50,50);
```

Since you intend to use 50x50 blocks, the right value for `xScale` and `yScale` would be 50.
You could go on from there and use:

```
 g.drawRect(xScale * j, yScale * i, xScale, yScale);
```

Once you've got that working, you should look into the [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) class, which will allow you a lot more options. But that's for later.

Comment: I see, now lets say my maze file gets bigger, and my scale is still quite large, that will mean it will cut of part of my maze. Does that i mean i need to automatically increase the window size? Is there a method for that rather than defining the size myself ?

Comment: @godlypython you could either calculate the scaling factor yourself (e.g. screen width/maze width) or just use a scrollpane, i.e. display only the visible part of your maze. For consistency I'd use a standard scaling factor which fits most mazes and a scrollpane for any maze that's too big (or you define a maximum maze size).

Comment: @godlypython You'll have to define the size yourself, unfortunately. An alternative is to put the maze inside a [Scroll Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

Comment: Ok thank you. The way I am currently doing it, is that its replacing hashtags and spacings. If i need to place a circle ontop in a position, does Java 2D allow overlapping of shapes?

Comment: @godlypython You can draw something over something else. I suppose the circle reprents the "player"? If that circle is going to move, you'll want to look up how to animate things in Java. The search terms "Java" and "animation" should get you started.

Comment: Indeed, i was planning on having two circles, one is the player and one dot as the end point with a specific position. Thanks for the help